# ¿Como crear una librería ReactJS CLI para NPM?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, npm

Hola amigos espero que estén muy bien, lo que requiero es poder llevar mi proyecto de REACTJS creado con:

```
create-react-app
```

A una librería de npm he intentado hacer los siguientes pasos:

1. Borro todos los archivos del src que genera el CLI menos el de serviceWorker y modifico el  index.js con un functional component.
2. Ejecutar el yarn build
3. Ejecutar el yarn link en el proyecto que quiero llevar a NPM
4. Ejecutar yarn link "prueba" en el proyecto donde lo quiero probar

El error que me saca es que no encuentra la ruta, sin embargo si me esta detectando el proyecto.
Entonces no tengo ni idea que tengo que hacer, por otro lado tengo la duda de si solo se sube el buil de la aplicación para el NPM o que es lo que se tiene que subir, y por lo que he visto del webpack que este proyecto tiene el entry tiene algo que dice es que estático que la verdad ni idea de ha que se refiere.
agradecería mucho la colaboración que tengan buen día.

Algo que posiblemente podría ayudar: [Ver esto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución era configurar el webpack de tal forma que me transpilara ES6 y JSX en ES5, y scss en css, generando los mismos archivos que tengo a nivel de desarrollo a nivel de transpilado, además de establecer un index como punto de acceso, y modificar el main package.json dándole la ruta del index creado como punto de acceso.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-simulator